# Ubuntu Live USB not detected for boot

Tags: boot

I created an Ubuntu bootable USB. It's not showing up in my BIOS and I don't know why.

[image]

As one can see here, I clearly created an Ubuntu bootable disk. There is no reason I shouldn't be able to detect this on startup, but here we are.

I also would normally use a DVD, except that was taking forever and freezing at install. Is this expected? I'll have to revert to Windows if so.

But yes, what is the workaround for this? I have Secure Boot enabled but my BIOS doesn't even SEE this usb drive.

Comment: If you have UEFI Secure Boot enabled, you usually have to turn on another setting to allow USB boot as USB boot is not considered secure. Check UEFI settings.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Glassjawed Check your boot settings in BOIS and I think olfred's comment will make sense.... Also, if you didn't create the USB drive using a boot-disk creator app it won't work